# What SMS email address works for Google Voice?

Tags: email, google-voice, sms

I have a Google Voice number that accepts SMS messages and I need an email address that can be used to send SMS messages to my Google Voice number.  What is the email address for Google Voice assuming my Google Voice phone number were: (201) 555-1234?

For example, if you have T-Mobile, you could use: 2015551234@tmomail.net

So what is the corresponding email address for Google Voice?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to investigate [IF This Then That](http://ifttt.com/wtf) and maybe their [recipe](http://ifttt.com/recipes/2434) that allows you to automatically forward a e-mail message to a phone via SMS. This recipe may not fully work for you, depending on your needs, but this is a start.

[ifttt](http://ifttt.com/) is truly a godsend when it comes to connecting different services.

Comment: The link to recipe seems broken.

Answer (score 2):

Google wants (and does) forward a Google text message to email itself. It puts some encrypted string along with. For example if you send a message from 222-333-4444 to 222-333-4445, the corresponding email address it would result is `12223334444.12223334445.m46hV-2FW5@txt.voice.google.com` and the reply should be from the same email to the same text otherwise it will not deliver.